# My validation and the push() is not working

Tags: javascript, validation

The user has to type the information in a text box and then click on the button to add the names. If the format is correct the name will appear below the text box.  If the format is incorrect a message will be generated that reads "Incorrect Format". 
The users inputs will create a list of names that will appear underneath the text box.

```
function validate(name){
    var str = [];
    var name = document.getElementById("letters");
    var check = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

    if(name.value.match(check)){
      str.push(document.getElementById("letters"));
       document.write("Name: " + name);

    }
    else{
        document.write("Incorrect Format");
    }
}
validate();
```

Comment: `var name = document.getElementById("letters").value;` and `str.push(document.getElementById("letters").value);`

Comment: If you already have the `name` and assuming it is corret as @dhilt mentioned, just push that: `str.push(name);`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```js
function validate() {
  console.clear();
  var check = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var inputVal = document.getElementById('letters').value;
  if (inputVal.match(check)) {
    console.log("Name: " + inputVal);
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += inputVal + "<br/>";
  } else {
    console.log("Incorrect Format");
  }
}


document.getElementById('btnValidate').addEventListener('click', validate);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="letters" />
<input type="button" id="btnValidate" value="Validate" />
<div id="container"></div>
```